# How to scrape multiple tables on URL with rvest in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to figure out how to scrape the tables on this page - https://transparentcalifornia.com/agencies/salaries/

I used the following to scrape the cities table:

```
url %>% 
html_node("table") %>%
html_table()
```

But I'd like to also scrape the preceding tables as well. I've looked through a few guides on how to possibly to this, including the following code, but can't seem to get it to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
url %>%
  html_node(".span9") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  toString() %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: `%>% html_node("table")` returns the first table `%>% html_nodes("table")` -note the the 's', returns all of the tables

Comment: Thanks for this! I knew the solution was going to be really simple but just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was able to bypass html_node and just use html_table to get all of the tables page with the following:

```
url %>% html_table()
```